# What is the reasoning for the imbalance of Scala's regular value assignment vs extractor assignment?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Scala appears to have different semantics for regular value assignment versus assignment during an extraction. This has created some very subtle runtime bugs for me as my codebase has migrated over time.

To illustrate:

```
case class Foo(s: String)

def anyRef(): AnyRef = { ... }

val Foo(x) = anyRef() // compiles but throws exception if anyRef() is not a Foo

val f: Foo = anyRef() // does not compile
```

I don't see why the two `val` assignment lines would be imbalanced with regard to compile/runtime behavior.

Some I am curious: Is there a reason for this behavior? Is it an undesirable artifact of the way the extraction is implemented?

(tested in Scala 2.11.7)

Comment: The LHS can either define a term (and optionally its type) or it can be an arbitrary pattern (that might bind names, too). http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions

Comment: Notoriously, you can write `val 1 = 2`. If you want handle the error, rewrite it as a match with a default case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

In the case of an extractor you are specifying a pattern that you expect to match at this position. This is translated to a call of an extractor method from Any to Option[String] and this method can be called with the value of type AnyRef you provide. You are just asserting, that you do indeed get a result and not "None".

In the other line you are using a type annotation, i.e. you are specifying the type of "f" explicitly. But then you are assigning an incompatible value.

Of course the compiler could add implicit type casts but making type casts so easy would not really suit a language like Scala.

You should also keep in mind that extractors have nothing to do with types. In the Pattern `Foo(x)` the name Foo has nothing to do with the type Foo. It is just the Name of an extractor method.

Using patterns in this way is of course a quite dynamic feature, but I think it is intentional.

Comment: This is not correct: `Foo` is a case class, and it's a constructor pattern, not an extractor pattern. The generated code checks `instanceof` and then just assigns the `Foo.s`. If the RHS is typed as `Foo`, of course, the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: names for these things at http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns

Comment: I guess I was hoping for an answer beyond just "because the spec and implementation say so".  Is there any valid use case where someone would want `val Foo(x) = anyRef()` to compile? Shouldn't it at least generate a warning?

Comment: Hm, you're right, there is more magic for case classes. The synthesised companion object indeed has an extractor method, however it has an argument of the case class. So these "constructor patterns" are not realised by the generated extractor. Why is it generated then anyway? The code for the pattern is indeed generated explicitly. Seems strange.

Comment: The reason for it is, I think, that patterns are supposed to allow you to make such assumptions. You can even match on a type in a pattern. And you can use regular expressions as patterns and so on. So this construct allows you to do unsafe stuff, why not match on a constructor.

Comment: The purists say don't do that, and why do you have `Any`; the pragmatists like the concision when they need it. You want a lint or Abide rule to flag such assignments that aren't "irrefutable" (may fail). For-comprehensions do filter refutable patterns. By coincidence, someone just asked a similar question on scala-user, which turns on `null.isInstanceOf`. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/xPFjJpAAP3w